# Trigger dragstart event in angular jasmine karma tests

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I am trying to make a check if a static property of the component has changed due to a drag of the component.
When I start the drag start event triggers a callback that sets a static property of the component.
However, when I try to test this I get undefined on the property( the drag start event is triggered as I was able to log to the console when the callback of the event is triggered.)
this is my test:

```
it('......',()=>{
    let circularContainer = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css(".border-wrapper"))
    console.log(circularContainer) // untill this point ok
    circularContainer.triggerEventHandler("dragstart",null) // ok - the function is triggered
    component.currentData = mockedData // the function uses the currentData and mocked data is just an imported object
    let id = CircularComponent.id // the static property that is set inside the function 
    fixture.detectChanges()
    expected(id).toBe(12) // the mocked data id is 12
 }
```

**inside the component:**

```
dragStart(){
  CircularComponent.id = this.currentData.id
}
```

why the test is done after triggering the event? maybe it is something with wait async time?

Comment: "undefined on the property" , which property ? which line in the shared code ?

Comment: id is undefined